# Kibana is not acessible locally

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm new to Kibana and trying to setup Elastic Stack locally (on Ubuntu 20.04) following this tutorial: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-elk-s..

All systemd services are running, but Kibana is not accessible.

`curl -XGET http://localhost:5601` results in `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5601: Connection refused`

netstat also shows that port 5601 is not listening. I've made these changes to kibana.yml:

```
server.name: "myname"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
```

`curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v` results in

```
health status index uuid pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green open .kibana_task_manager_7.13.0_001 dRod_dCJQ_KgKweb3rWEUQ 1 0 2 0 15.2kb 15.2kb
green open .apm-custom-link TSK6nQ3xTl2LrPvIwYKjOQ 1 0 0 0 208b 208b
green open .kibana-event-log-7.13.0-000001 2p7tc_x4Tba6Ap7DgXW4Xw 1 0 1 0 5.6kb 5.6kb
green open .apm-agent-configuration bBSQIxt9RRqtC-4OCYxX0Q 1 0 0 0 208b 208b
green open .kibana_7.13.0_001 r1cA1n0bQEWalaihnFlzCw 1 0 6 0 2.1mb 2.1mb
yellow open filebeat-7.13.0-2021.05.29-000001 TyEjogC9T2mzQoG01NRwWg 1 1 0 0 208b 208b
```

Sometimes Kibana flips to "Kibana server is not ready yet" for a moment, but this also happened before installing Filebeat.

kibana.log contains no errors. What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue happened for timing out for the Kibana connection, First of all make sure that you Elasticsearch server is up and running (the default port is on 9200 ) and by typing the localhost:9200 on a browser you must get following massage

```html
{
  "name" : "D-N-PC-****",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "****",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.11.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "****",
    "build_date" : "****",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Then go to the bin directory of where you downloaded Kibana and execute the shell/batch file of Kibana by
`./kibana.bat` then wait a bit to Kibana get connected to you database then open a browser and type `localhost:5601` more over you can modify your Kibana configuration file by going to `config` directory of Kibana and modify the default value but if you are new to elastic then you must procced with default auto configurations as the place you didn't change the default values.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped, also had to unlock the indices by curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://[YOUR_ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT]:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'. I guess it was also one of the causes of the problem

Comment: Happy to helped ! Good luck !